# Django Forms (Displaying labels)

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, label

I have a problem as I ant to have radio buttons list like this:

1)

```
 How would you rate the content of this site?
 Poor o1 o2 o3 o4 o5 Excellent
```

But is any possibility to do it in django forms?
As now I have:

```
 How would you rate the content of this site?

 o o1
 o o2
 o o3
 o o4
 o o5
```

:/

2)

And I have another question like this. Can I do like this?

```
 Label:
 TextArea here
```

as I have

```
 Label: textArea here :/
```

3)

Is any possibility to put labels into this django forms without creating any field?
I mean e.x.:
     Section1:(label)

```
 Name: texbox
 Phone: textbox

 Section2:

 hobby: textbox
```

etc?
I was looking for a good documentation but I couldn't find what I need I mean there weren't to much details :/
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes - when you use your form in your template, you can interact with the fields individually by accessing `form.fieldname` - like so:

```
<p>How would you rate the content of this site?</p>
Poor
{{ form.rating }}
Excellent
```

If you want to position a form field's label and field differently, you can do that too:

```
{{ form.fieldname.label }}: {{ form.fieldname }}
```

And when it comes to displaying labels without a form there, you should be able to just add them to your markup yourself - you don't need Django for that.